# Ways to render dot/graphviz in web2py?

Tags: d3.js, graphviz, web2py

What is the best/proper way to make a d3 graphviz graph in web2py? How can I use the d3-js files of the admin app?

```
d3.select("#graph").graphviz().renderDot("digraph {a -> c}");
```

Comment: I don't know web2py at all. Taking a quick look, though, it would appear to be a tool to author web apps in Python. If correct, I would think the natural approach would be to use [Python's graphviz](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/).